# Checking a folder for a file

Tags: c#, .net

What is the best way to perform the following with c#:

- Need to check a folder and find all Files that start with E and have 2 numbers after the E and have a file ext for .chk.
- Then I need to find the file with the lowest number after the E.

Ex)

```
E03.chk
E01.chk
E02.chk
```

in this example, I would need to get E01.chk file name returned.

Comment: couple of things: there's no such thing as C#.NET. The language is named "C#". Also, you don't need to include "C# .NET" in the title, since you've got that in the tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^E\d\d$");
var file = Directory.GetFiles(path, "E??.chk")
                    .Where(f => regex.IsMatch(File.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f)))
                    .OrderBy(f => f)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use FileInfo and DirectoryInfo from System.IO.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the Directory class, specifically: [`Directory.EnumerateFiles()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571.aspx), which accepts a search wildcard pattern.